# Can a hive udtf parse a map which takes in a key as string but value can be any object

Tags: hive

I am trying to write a hive udtf . My udtf looks something like this:
udtf(map(string,map(string,string),string,string)
In the above example the value of the map is again a map or it can be a string or it can be any other object. Is it possible to implement a udtf like this. If yes then how the converters can be created .